# Выполнить один раз функцию

Tags: php, jquery

Всем привет. Есть реализация уведомления, чуть чуть кривовата, но есть. 
Когда человек добавляет объявление, он переходит по ссылке [http://доме.com?post=1](http://%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5.com?post=1)
Как видно есть GET параметр. В начале страницы есть такой костыль

```
<?if (isset($_GET['post'])){?>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

      //Показываю уведомление 
    }); 




</script>
<?;}?>
```

Все работает, но есть одна проблема. Человек остатся на этой же странице, и если он обновляет страницу то ему опять показывается уведомление? Конечно можно и нужно решить все через ajax, но на данный момент такой возможности не имеется. Есть варианты как показать единожды уведомление?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Перенаправлять не на  `http://доме.com?post=1` а  на `http://доме.com?post=1#message`

При показе сообщения яваскиптом добавить

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if(location.hash == "message"){
      // Тут показывает сообщение, а потом:
      location.hash = '';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно где-то в теле js-скрипта добавить:

```
window.history.replaceState({}, 'title', 'http://доме.com');
```

Здесь третий параметр - новый "текущий" URL. Т.е. мы убираем из адреса параметр post=1.

При обновлении страницы запрос будет отправлен без этого параметра.

В контексте данной задачи первые 2 параметра метода replaceState не имеют значения.

Answer (score -1):

Можно положить флаг в `LocalStorage` о том, что уведомление уже показано, и далее проверять в `$.ready()`